# Testing a linear combination of coefficients in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

Let's say I have the following regression:

```
mort_probit <- glm(mort ~ age + I(age*age) + hs_grad + some_college + college + post_grad + black + hisp + other + rich + middle_class, family = binomial("probit"), data=data)
```

This is set up such that the base case is a poor white.  I want to test if a wealthy black individual has a lower risk for mortality than a poor white.

I set up a linear combination of coefficients in the following way:

```
summary(glht(mort_probit, linfct = c("(black + rich) = 0 ")))
```

But I'm not sure if this answers my question.  What exactly is this command doing?  I'm guessing it sets "black" and "rich" to 1 and test if that minus the base case = 0.

What is the correct way of doing this?